# Javascript cannot find hidden Field in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, postback

I am trying save the disabled property value of a hidden field to track the disabled state of a button between postbacks, with the following javascript

```
function TrackState(buttonID)
{
   var trackingField = document.getElementById("_tracking" + buttonID);

    return false; // prevent default action
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="_trackingButton1" value="true" />
```

but trackingField seems to be null each time, what is going wrong here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the id property of your element (not just name) and it should work like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="_trackingButton1" name="_trackingButton1" value="true" />
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It won't get posted back unless it also has a `name` property.

Answer (score 1):

In your function

function TrackState(buttonID)
{
}

what is the buttonID value exactly. I hope it is "Button1". 
And as the function says getElementById the input has the property id with the same value.

Comment: +1 my thought initially as well, I was just about to type it out and saw you got it covered

Answer (score 1):

The getElementById() method specifically looks for id values:

```
<input type="hidden" id="_trackingButton1" name="_trackingButton1" value="true" />
```